# How do I get SSL certificates for my golang application?

Tags: security, go, ssl

I'm currently building an application and I want to make sure that I use HTTPS throughout the whole application. The application is a web application in Golang and I wanted to know how to get legit certificates so that my application can be secure.

Comment: [`golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert) is probably the easiest way to manage this from the application itself; but there are many proxies and external tools available as mentioned by some of the answers, and if your needs are simple enough then those should be more than enough.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it depends on how the application is gonna be deployed.

*Hosting the application on a VPS / private server as a systemd service ?*

You could look into [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org) if you want to manage SSL renewal automatically. But still you'll need to provide the certificate into your application, or use a HTTP proxy such as NGINX to expose your application on HTTPS.

This approach would work, but can be painful as you'll need to install / manage Certbot & possibly Nginx on your server.

Another good option would be to use [Traefik](https://docs.traefik.io), it's a Proxy server with builtin [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) support, so that you'll be able to use free SSL, automatically renewed, by just installing the service, and creating a little configuration file.

I would personally choose the external proxy approach on this one, and especially Traefik. It shouldn't be the job of you web application to manage HTTPS, but more an external proxy. So that if one day you need to scale your application, it shouldn't be painful.

Comment: I was planning on deploying the application to AWS and running on and with AWS services.

Comment: Then maybe you should look into The AWS certificate manager https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a few options. I found it easy to use [ZeroSSL](https://zerossl.com/) to get a trusted certificate, but there are **many** other ways to do so. You can also use [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/), but it several dependencies to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting certificate for FQDN , you can use Letusencrypt which provides many clients support including certbot. You can find it here
https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/ but please remember it wont work without fqdn.